# How to get rid off error in gradle files in new flamingo version of Android studio to connect bitnami perse server from AWS

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, native, bitnami

What change can I made in gradle build files so that I connect the parse server from aws EC2 bitnami in my new flamingo version of Android studio?

I tried from previous courses codes but it gives error and I searched youtubes as well for this but these codes also not works